# Scala-Spark flattening nested schema contains array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a nested schema which contains array:

```
 root
  |-- alarm_time: string (nullable = true)
  |-- alarm_id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- family: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- postalcode: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- line1: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true) 
  |-- device: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- device_usage: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- device_id: string (nullable = true)  
  |-- alarm_info: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- reason: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- alarm_severity: long (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- extra_info: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- producer: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- comment: string (nullable = true)
```

I used to ignore array fields and used this code to flatten my schema:

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
    val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

    f.dataType match {
      case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
      case _ => Array(col(colName))
    }
  })
}
```

And use it like `df.select(flattenSchema(df.schema):_*)` but now I have a use-case which needs to keep the array data too, the only thing I can think of is to **explode** the array and keep multiple rows but I have no luck. Since I am passing the column as args argument I cannot pass another argument.

How can I achieve this (to have flattened schema with an exploded array)?

Comment: So you want to call `explode` on the array column as well as flatten the structure in the same `select`? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Shaido yes you are right I want to have a separate column for each element of array

Comment: Do you want to have a separate column or row for each element? Using `explode` you will get the elements on their own rows, not columns.

Comment: @Shaido I want to get separate columns for each element of array (after exploding the array). I mean if I have a row with an array of two it should generate 2 row with each of array element but array element should have separate columns each (producer, comment)

Comment: I understand, in this case, can't you just explode the array first and then use `flattenSchema` on the new dataframe? In this case, the array would already have been exploded into multiple rows which all contains a struct (each with two elements, producer and comment) and your method should be able to flatten it.

Comment: @Shaido currently I am doing like this, but I wanted to do it in just one recursive method since I have other schemas too with different number of array

Comment: @Am1rr3zA, assuming this to be a JSON document, did you try using get_json_object function of spark sql? If you want to extract 'name' from 'user' struct, df.withColumn("name", get_json_object($"json_string_col", "$.user.name"))

Comment: it's needed to be in one shot I cannot add each column by withColumn since I don't know the schema's hierarchy and name in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Am1rr3zA, the solution you have provided would break if we have two arrays at same level. It would not allow two explosions at same time : "Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 2: explode(_1), explode(_2)"

I have updated the solution to keep track of complex types within nesting

```
  def flattenDataFrame(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {

var flattenedDf: DataFrame = df

if (isNested(df)) {

  val flattenedSchema: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = flattenSchema(df.schema)
  var simpleColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]
  var complexColumns: List[Column] = List.empty[Column]

  flattenedSchema.foreach {
    case (col, isComplex) => {
      if (isComplex) {
        complexColumns = complexColumns :+ col
      } else {
        simpleColumns = simpleColumns :+ col
      }
    }
  }

  var crossJoinedDataFrame = df.select(simpleColumns: _*)
  complexColumns.foreach(col => {
    crossJoinedDataFrame = crossJoinedDataFrame.crossJoin(df.select(col))
    crossJoinedDataFrame = flattenDataFrame(crossJoinedDataFrame)
  })
  crossJoinedDataFrame
} else {
  flattenedDf
}
```

}

```
private def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null): Array[(Column, Boolean)] = {

schema.fields.flatMap(field => {

  val columnName = if (prefix == null) field.name else prefix + "." + field.name
  field.dataType match {
    case arrayType: ArrayType => {
      val cols: Array[(Column, Boolean)] = Array[(Column, Boolean)](((explode_outer(col(columnName)).as(columnName.replace(".", "_"))), true))
      cols
    }
    case structType: StructType => {
      flattenSchema(structType, columnName)
    }
    case _ => {
      val columnNameWithUnderscores = columnName.replace(".", "_")
      val metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putString("encoding", "ZSTD").build()
      Array(((col(columnName).as(columnNameWithUnderscores, metadata)), false))
    }
  }
}).filter(field => field != None)
```

}

```
def isNested(df: DataFrame): Boolean = {
df.schema.fields.flatMap(field => {

  field.dataType match {
    case arrayType: ArrayType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case mapType: MapType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case structType: StructType => {
      Array(true)
    }
    case _ => {
      Array(false)
    }
  }
}).exists(b => b)
```

}

Comment: Where is `isNested` defined?

Comment: @PaulReiners, I only mentioned the parts that I touched from original solution. I have added isNested definition in my comment now ... 

Comment: this is pretty good example. really helps to flatten it.  I have a very little change in my requirement. if anybody can give advice for it.
Suppose i have schema like below
{
a
|-b
|  |-c
}. examlaining it -> 
a is main tag under that b is the tag, under b, c is the tag. c is having two records. Using this method generates two records in dataframe out of one record. If i need one record with both tag values seperated by ; then how can i apply it ?

Answer (score 0):

So what I am doing right now (**Spark 2.2+**) is to check if a schema is nested and call `flattenschema` over and over again till it gets flattened.

```
  def makeItFlat(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    if (isSchemaNested(df)) {
      val flattenedSchema = flattenSchema(df.schema)
      makeItFlat(df.select(flattenedSchema: _*))
    }
    else {
      df
    }
  }
```

makeItFlat() is a recursive method that checks if the schema is not flattened yet recursively call flattenschema again

```
  def isSchemaNested(df: DataFrame): Boolean = {
    df.schema.fields.flatMap(field => {

      field.dataType match {
        case arrayType: ArrayType => {
          Array(true)
        }
        case mapType: MapType => {
          Array(true)
        }
        case structType: StructType => {
          Array(true)
        }
        case _ => {
          Array(false)
        }
      }
    }).exists(b => b)
  }
```

The job of isSchemaNested is to check if there is any nested datatype in the schema's defenition

```
  private def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null): Array[Column] = {
    schema.fields.flatMap(field => {
      val columnName = if (prefix == null) field.name else prefix + "." + field.name

      field.dataType match {
        case arrayType: ArrayType => {

          Array[Column](explode_outer(col(columnName)).as(columnName.replace(".", "_")))
        }
        case mapType: MapType => {
          None
        }
        case structType: StructType => {

          flattenSchema(structType, columnName)
        }
        case _ => {
          val columnNameWithUnderscores = columnName.replace(".", "_")

          val metadata = new MetadataBuilder().putString("encoding", "ZSTD").build()

          Array(col(columnName).as(columnNameWithUnderscores, metadata))
        }
      }
    }).filter(field => field != None)
  }
```